# replace &qoute: with " " in string in android

Tags: android, json, string, android-volley

i am using volley request and in response i am getting folloiwng

```
[{

&quot;body&quot;:

&quot;Jazz Your Offer se abhi *303# milain aur enjoy karaen poora din 50 JazzWarid minutes siraf Rs 10 bama tax mai&quot;,

&quot;address&quot;:&quot;JAZZ&quot;,
&quot;

date&quot;:&quot;November 12, 2019&quot;,&quot;

time&quot;:&quot;Tuesday, 10:49:45 AM&quot;

}]
```

What i want , i want clear json array like

```
[
  {
    "body": "Alhumdulilah.. ap snao",
    "address": "+92XXXXXXXXXX",
    "date": "October 09, 2019",
    "time": "Wednesday, 8:56:23 PM"
  },
  {
    "body": "Alhumdulilah.. ap snao",
    "address": "+923XXXXXXXXX",
    "date": "October 09, 2019",
    "time": "Wednesday, 8:56:23 PM"
  }
]
```

how can i achieve in android ?

Comment: First Store all data then check if data contains & then replace with "".

Comment: how can i do this.  i have tried but not worked???

Comment: Post your code so I can get more information.

Comment: Try this `string.replace("&quot;", "'");`

Comment: or you can format your code with `Html.fromHtml(your data)`

Comment: single qoutes are not working i want to replace it with double here ?   can i do it

Comment: Yes it will all you need is replace `&quot;` with your requirements.

Comment: Or you can pass empty string

Comment: Try to convert your response to JSONArray:  `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);`

Comment: Try this text.replace("&quot;", "\"");

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jsonString.replace("&quot;", " ")
```

to replace occurencies of `"&quot;"` with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` to overcome this problem

```
String formattedResponse = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
        response, 
        HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
```

Comment: @muhammad-ashfaq, did you get your answer. Let me know